# how to resolve "ssh error occurred during unpacking on the remote end: unpack-objects abnormal exit" in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, ssh

After cloning git-repo, when i try to push the repo to git server after commit. It gives error as "ssh error occurred during unpacking on the remote end: unpack-objects abnormal exit"

Comment: The remote end disliked you.  Can you push from the command line outside Eclipse?

Comment: i tried from command line but the same error occurs again

Comment: Then it is most likely an error in the remote end.  Have a look at the ssh logs on the remote end.

Comment: how to look at the ssh logs on the remote end?

Comment: If a fresh clone exhibits the same problem, talk to the administrators of the remote system.

Answer (score 1):

Check the ownership of your remote repo.
I run into this problem as well. My remote repo was created by other user(in my case, root) rather than git(the user to manage git operations).
So I changed the ownership of this repo to git.

```
chown -R git:git xxxxxx.git
```

Hope it helps.